# Caching an Umbraco website running on IIS 7.x with .NET 4.0 on an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, iis-7, .net, cache

What are the available options for caching an Umbraco website on AWS EC2?

So far, we've considered using Varnish but it's not recommended for a production environment. Is there a de-facto HTTP accelerator for IIS like Varnish? https://www.varnish-cache.org/

It is a legacy website, so I'm not 100% certain that all the necessary caching has been performed within the application code (e.g. macro caching)

We're aiming to meet a traffic profile of 60 page requests a second for 3 minute peak (excluding additional requests for CSS, JavaScript and other static assets.)

Would really appreciate some recommendations, particularly anyone who deals with Umbraco deployments on this scale!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not run a Linux/Varnish box infront of the slow IIS servers?

> Varnish but it's not recommended for a production environment.

We use Varnish in production on EC2 :) Requests are first routed through Nginx load balancers then routed to an available App server. App servers runs Varnish on 80 and App server on 8080.  User sessions are stored in a Memcached pool which is available to all currently running App servers.

Comment: This is exactly what I gathered after posting this!